# Ionic 2 JSON dates and moment.js trouble

Tags: json, date, ionic-framework, momentjs

I have a problem with dates manipulation with Ionic and moment.js.
I store some dates from a ion-datetime component :

```
{"year":2017,"month":7,"day":26,"hour":null,"minute":null,"second":null,"millisecond":null,"tzOffset":0}
```

And use moment.js to "humanize" date display :

```
let somedate = moment(some.date);
console.log('JSON date : ' + JSON.stringify(some.date) + ' resolved as : ' + somedate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

And got result :

```
Original JSON date : {"year":2017,"month":7,"day":26,"hour":null,"minute":null,"second":null,"millisecond":null,"tzOffset":0} resolved as : 26/08/2017
```

As you can consider, there's on month offset between original JSON date and moment display date...

What i'm missing ?

Comment: I suppose , both dates are correct ,I dont know about ionic-framework but JS months run from 0-11 wherein moment shows you actual month , so august in JS will be 7 , but its actual 8th month.

Comment: In [`moment(Object)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/) docs: _Note that like `moment(Array)` and `new Date(year, month, date)`, months are 0 indexed._

Answer (score 2):

The Javascript month are in range of 0-11 i.e. January is 0, February is 1 and likewise, therefore it is moving you to the next month. Try subtracting 1 from month value, to get the correct month.

```js
var some = {'date':{"year":2017,"month":6,"day":26,"hour":null,"minute":null,"second":null,"millisecond":null,"tzOffset":0} };

let somedate = moment(some.date);
console.log('JSON date : ' + JSON.stringify(some.date) + ' resolved as : ' + somedate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, with your answers, i resolved the problem with a conversion method that take the original JSON date format and return a Javascript Date object, using TypeScript :

```
  private _JSONDateToDate(jsonDate: any){
if(typeof jsonDate == 'object')
  return new Date(jsonDate.year, (parseInt(jsonDate.month) - 1), jsonDate.day);

return jsonDate;
```

}

I substract 1 month of the "month" property in order to have a correct Date object... then, i can manipulate it with moment.js